# How to override default download/save button handler?

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to make an extension that opens the downloads manager window as a sidebar or some other way, and not a new window.

- For this, I must first stop the "Save" button, in the "Save Dialog", from opening the downloads manager as a new window.
- And then, I must set the `oncommand` attribute of the button to my custom function.

**What I think, could be done : (Please see the edit, instead of this)**

(If I have the id of the "Save" button in the "Save dialog", I could 
`removeAttribute("oncommand")` and then `setAttribute("oncommand", "some_other_function");`

Though, I am extremely unclear about whether the updated attribute will last. If the Save dialog is opened by a `openDialog` call (INTERNALLY), a new one would appear every time.

- Is this the right way of doing it? What then, is the id of the "Save" button? (Also, how can I know when the "Save dialog" is opened? That is when the save button would have any meaning.)
- How else could it be done?)

**EDIT :**

I think it would be possible via XPCOM interfaces. **Is there someway by which I can** :

- Know when a download/save is initiated?
- Get access to the Save dialog that opens after the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** I could tell when a download started using the [nsiDownloadService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIObserverService) XPCOM interface.

```
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(this, "dl-start", false);
```

`dl-start` was the required topic id.
(I could not find where `dl-start` is documented in MDN. Could someone point it out, please?)

**2 -** I just had to set the preference `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting` to `false` to stop Firefox from opening it's own Download Manager in a new window.